# Correct use of StreamWriter

Tags: c#, tcp

After several attempts I can't get StreamWriter to build / work corectly so I am doing something fundamentally wrong (C#, Visual Studio)

I have an exisitng TCP Client which connects and acts as a reader, this is working without fault -

```
private System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream ns;
        private System.IO.StreamReader sr;
        private string strIP;
        private string strPort;
        public System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient tc;

        public Socketclient(Reader.Search objSearch)
        {
            m_search = objSearch;
        }

        public void EthernetConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                bool flag = !System.IO.File.Exists(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\IPAddress.txt");
                if (!flag)
                {
                    System.IO.TextReader textReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\IPAddress.txt");
                    string s = textReader.ReadLine();
                    textReader.Close();
                    char[] chArr = new char[] { ';' };
                    string[] sArr = s.Split(chArr);
                    strPort = sArr[0];
                    strIP = sArr[1];
                    flag = strIP == System.String.Empty || strPort == System.String.Empty;
                    if (!flag)
                    {
                        int i = System.Convert.ToInt16(strPort);
                        tc = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(strIP, i);
                        flag = !tc.Connected;
                        if (!flag)
                        {
                            ns = tc.GetStream();
                            sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ns);
                            m_search.threadClient = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
                            m_search.threadClient.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Lowest;
                            m_search.threadClient.Name = "Ethernet Thread";


   }
```

I then want to add (in another .cs which is part of the same application) a StreamWriter thread to write back some characters to the same port and then close the StreamWriter thread (leaving the reader running) -

```
private System.IO.StreamWriter sw;

string line = "TH1/r/n";
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns));
sw.WriteLine(line);
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

Which, somehow (I think) needs to refer back to

```
ns = tc.GetStream();
```

Any thougts appreciated

Regards
Active

Comment: Sounds like this question is not about `StreamWriter` or tcp, but about basic class design? So it's a little broad and hard to tell without seeing your project. If you want to access `sw` in your whole class, make it a field of your class. If you even want to access it from outside the class (different .cs-file), create a public property that exposes the value. But this is basic c# stuff you should actually know before asking here, but maybe I misunderstand the question.

Comment: `How do I reference the already running client (in a separate .cs)` When you establish connection from your client to the server, you need to store the `TcpClient` reference for future access. Are you doing that? If yes, then either `tc` or `ns` should be alive and in scope for you to access and call `sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(tc.GetStream());` or `sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ns);`. If not, then we will need to see all the **relevant** code

Comment: It looks like you are posting chunks put together from your code. We need to see the actual method or class. The way you posted it, it looks like it IS in context.

Comment: I need a simple to understand example of StreamWriter

Comment: you have posted an incomplete section of your code, with another portion that isn't related.  please revise your question and write with clarity, please

Answer (score 0):

this sort of question has been asked many times already.

[Receving and sending data in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836811/receving-and-sending-data-in-c-sharp)

brief cut and past from example above showing sending of data

```
using(TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("ADDRESS"))
{
    NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    using(StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: StreamWriter has to have an argument (ns) which somehow has to refer back to ns = tc.GetStream() and of course ns is not in context in this .cs

Comment: ns is your stream?  and tc is of what type, TcpClient?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836811/receving-and-sending-data-in-c-sharp  your question is a duplicate!

Comment: ns is private System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream ns;  and tc is TcpClient

Comment: Changing ns to public System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream ns; makes no difference (ns out of context in separate .cs)

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but that starts another TCP Client and the server currently doesn't allow that.

Comment: I understand. this is not 'exactly' what you need.  you will need to slightly modify the code to 'fit' your exact requirement.  this is all basic stuff that 'I' am 'easily' finding by doing a google search.  NetworkStream, in this example, can simply be replaced with the member you have defined someplace else.  TcpClient can also be replaced too.  instead of using a using simply close both TcpClient and NetworkStream when you are finished with them

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the using block around StreamWriter, removing it allowed the underlying stream to continue.