# Correct use of StreamWriter (again)

Tags: c#

After several attempts I can't get StreamWriter to build / work corectly so I am doing something fundamentally wrong (C#, Visual Studio)

I have an exisitng TCP Client which connects and acts as a reader, this is working without fault -

```
private System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream ns;
        private System.IO.StreamReader sr;
        private string strIP;
        private string strPort;
        public System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient tc;

        public Socketclient(Reader.Search objSearch)
        {
            m_search = objSearch;
        }

        public void EthernetConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                bool flag = !System.IO.File.Exists(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\IPAddress.txt");
                if (!flag)
                {
                    System.IO.TextReader textReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\IPAddress.txt");
                    string s = textReader.ReadLine();
                    textReader.Close();
                    char[] chArr = new char[] { ';' };
                    string[] sArr = s.Split(chArr);
                    strPort = sArr[0];
                    strIP = sArr[1];
                    flag = strIP == System.String.Empty || strPort == System.String.Empty;
                    if (!flag)
                    {
                        int i = System.Convert.ToInt16(strPort);
                        tc = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(strIP, i);
                        flag = !tc.Connected;
                        if (!flag)
                        {
                            ns = tc.GetStream();
                            sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ns);
                            m_search.threadClient = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
                            m_search.threadClient.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Lowest;
                            m_search.threadClient.Name = "Ethernet Thread";


   }
```

I then want to add (in another .cs which is part of the same application) a StreamWriter thread to write back some characters to the same port and then close the StreamWriter thread (leaving the reader running) -

```
private System.IO.StreamWriter sw;

string line = "TH1/r/n";
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns));
sw.WriteLine(line);
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

Which, somehow (I think) needs to refer back to

```
ns = tc.GetStream();
```

Any thougts appreciated

Regards
Active

Comment: Please edit your [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46281252/correct-use-of-streamwriter).

Comment: if you cannot get this to 'build', as you state, then please provide the error message the compiler is giving you.  if this is a runtime error please provide that. OR if the code is not running as expected please compose your question to better explain this issue.  as is we are having trouble understanding exactly what is going on